# How to create website visitor tracking to app install - using app login with Facebook / PhoneGap

Tags: android, ios, facebook-graph-api, phonegap-build, affiliate

I created a PhoneGap app (IOS & Android) that uses login with Facebook.  My back end server then verifies the Facebook token, gets the ID, email, name, etc.

I want to pay people who promote my mobile app for each user that installs the app.

I have tested login with Facebook on my website which would do the trick (ID from website login matches ID from app login), but it does not make sense to have people login on my website.  I would need to give visitors some special incentive to do that.

I know Facebook has a pixel code, but I know they use it for their own gain only (I.E. CPI app ads).

I need a simple way to connect my affiliate driven visitor to an app install.

One thought is to cookie them and then open a webpage in the app to retrieve the cookie but they would need to open the page with the same web browser (I have 3 on my phone).

Any thoughts on how to easily do this?

Comment: Define “promote”. What do you want those users to do?

Comment: Install the mobile app and login with Facebook, at least start using it.

Comment: I want people that talk about it in social media to have a link that I can give them $ when their efforts pay off.

Comment: You are not allowed to reward people for posting your stuff on their personal profiles in any way. See https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse, 4.5

Comment: My app is not built upon Facebook.  It uses login only as an easy means to create an account. I could have just as easily given them an option to create an account with an email address and password.  None the less, the link you sent says "Only incentivize a person to log into your app" which is what happens when you run my mobile app.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your app only uses Facebook login - you have to follow platform policy. And rewarding users for posting links to/about your app on Facebook is not allowed. When they catch you, they will simply block your app and remove the links posted about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use branch.io to power your deeplinks and referrals. they are able to manage multiple cases. For cordova/phonegap here is where you can start. https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking

Comment: Not sure how deep linking works in a SPA (single page app).  I have seen several third parties that offer paid services like this.  I am kind of hoping for a simple solution I can implement now.

Comment: By "implement now" I mean without modify the app, which means a new version to IOS & Android stores.  If when they come to the landing page I give them a reason to log in with Facebook, then I will have their ID and then I will know when they install and use the app.  There would be nothing needed to be done with the app.